# Getting latest Tweets with API 1.1

Tags: twitter

I've always used this address to get all my tweets:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=enriquemoreno

but since API 1.1 is out and API 1 is deprecated I thought I would try change. But the new address is not working:

http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=enriquemoreno

What am I missing?

Comment: You should find your answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1

Comment: Here you'll find an example of fetching users tweets using the twitter 1.1 REST api and curl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1

Comment: There is a C# solution available here now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/17071447#17071447

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Someone](https://plus.google.com/+JasonMayes/posts/j65ntqa5Qd3) wrote a (clever) snippet in vanilla javascript that fetches twitter widgets:

```
/*********************************************************************
      #### Twitter Post Fetcher! ####
      Coded by Jason Mayes 2013.
      www.jasonmayes.com
      Please keep this disclaimer with my code if you use it. Thanks. :-)
      Got feedback or questions, ask here: http://goo.gl/JinwJ
    *********************************************************************/
    var twitterFetcher=function(){var d=null;return{fetch:function(a,b){d=b;var c=document.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/"+a+"?&lang=en&callback=twitterFetcher.callback&suppress_response_codes=true&rnd="+Math.random();document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)},callback:function(a){var b=document.createElement("div");b.innerHTML=a.body;a=b.getElementsByClassName("e-entry-title");d(a)}}}();

    /*
    * ### HOW TO USE: ###
    * Create an ID:
    * Go to www.twitter.com and sign in as normal, go to your settings page.
    * Go to "Widgets" on the left hand side.
    * Create a new widget for "user timeline". Feel free to check "exclude replies"
    * if you dont want replies in results.
    * Now go back to settings page, and then go back to widgets page, you should
    * see the widget you just created. Click edit.
    * Now look at the URL in your web browser, you will see a long number like this:
    * 345735908357048478
    * Use this as your ID below instead!
    */

    twitterFetcher.fetch('345170787868762112', function(tweets){
      // Do what you want with your tweets here! For example:
      var x = tweets.length;
      var n = 0;
      var element = document.getElementById('tweets');
      var html = '<ul>';
      while(n < x) {
        if (tweets[n].innerText) {
          html += '<li>' + tweets[n].innerText + '</li>';
        } else {
          html += '<li>' + tweets[n].textContent + '</li>';
        }
        n++;
      }
      html += '</ul>';
      element.innerHTML = html;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmayes/maT2Z/

Not the cleanest way and maybe not future-proof, but for now the only solution (I know) to access twitter data without OAuth and server-side support.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a pretty simple implementation with authorization & php:

http://profabbynucup.tumblr.com/post/53031776012/display-your-latest-twitter-feed-using-php-and-oauth

Comment: url gone. this is why you dont make url only answers.