# How do I update to new twitter API?

Tags: twitter

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=trekradio&include_rts=1&count=3&callback=twitterCallback2

This no longer works.

How can I get it to work on the new API?

I changed it to:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=trekradio&include_rts=1&count=3&callback=twitterCallback2

This returns an error and I do not know how to work around it.

Comment: Did you read the overview at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview which states "Authentication required on all endpoints"? You need to have an authentication token to make any API calls.

Comment: Have you looked at this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390398/getting-latest-tweets-with-api-1-1?rq=1

Comment: I did this in c#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/17071447#17071447

Comment: Well that is just ridiculously difficult now......